# How can i use jquery or javascrip to check link from google drive is avariable?

Tags: jquery, google-drive-api

I am writing the system to check available google drive links from users.
A user will share the public link from their google drive (Anyone with the link).
To make sure that I would link to check every link from users. It can be accessed.

Therefore, I try to use javascript to check their link.
This is my example code.

```
$('#videoCkeck').on('click', function () {
      console.log("check");
      fetch('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AunwLGuDlprNnM8KBIl7zZLLrYISCGFz/view?usp=sharing')
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response.status: ', response.status); // ️ 200
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error",err);
    });
      
    });
```

The google link in the above code can be accessed but I got some error when I tried to check it.

[image: error]

This is an error that I got it.

Please anyone suggest me? Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `check their link`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean check the link that is provided by the user.

Comment: I found the solution. I write PHP to check the status. I send the URL to my PHP code.
This is my solution.
  // Initialize an URL to the variable
  // Use get_headers() function
  $headers = @get_headers($url);
  // print_r($headers);
  // Use condition to check the existence of URL
  if($headers && strpos( $headers[0], '200')) {
   $status = "URL Exist";
   // print_r($headers);
  }
  else {
   $status = "URL Doesn't Exist";
  }
  
  // Display result
  echo($status);

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I write PHP to check the status. I send the URL to my PHP code.
This is my solution.

```
// Initialize an URL to the variable
// Use get_headers() function
$headers = @get_headers($url);
// print_r($headers);
// Use condition to check the existence of URL
if($headers && strpos( $headers[0], '200')) {
    $status = "URL Exist";
    // print_r($headers);
}
else {
    $status = "URL Doesn't Exist";
}

// Display result
echo($status);
```